# What would a linear mixed model look like in an experiment using human judgement?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, crossed-random-effects

I am trying to build a LME model for the following occasion:
In an experiment 10 persons rated 15 items (all rated the same items). These items can be physically (sensors) characterised by different parameters. These parameters will be my independent variables and the ratings (using a likert scale) my dependent variable.
Input table looks something like this:

[image]

Is the following formula then true for best describing the relationship between the objective (sensors) and subjective (human) perception of these items? (Crossed random effects model)

Ratings~parameter1+parameter2+(1|Raters)+(1|objects)

Thank you in advance for taking time to respond to my question!
Greetings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ! The proposed model:

```
Ratings~parameter1+parameter2+(1|Raters)+(1|objects)
```

is appropriate for analysing a design with crossed random effects.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: Cant help but think, since the parameters describe physically each one of the objects (parameters have the same number of levels as the number of objects) which are a grouping factor, shouldnt there be in the model a correlation? Something like: Ratings~ parameter1+parameter2+(1|Raters)+(parameter1|objects)+(parameter2|objects) However if I compare the betas of the original lme model ( ''Ratings~parameter1+parameter2+(1|Raters)+(1|objects) '') and the aggregated model (responses were averaged for each object) they are exactly the same.. Looking forward to your reply!